# load code from a code cell from one jupyter notebook into another jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to load (i.e., copy the code as with %load) the code from a code cell in one jupyter notebook into another jupyter notebook (Jupyter running Python, but not sure if that matters). I would really like to enter something like

```
%load cell[5] notebookname.ipynb
```

The command copies all code in cell 5 of `notebookname.ipynb` to the code cell of the notebook I am working on. Does anybody know a trick how to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems like a bad pattern. If you have reusable code, rather make a python module, and import it into both notebooks.

Comment: Following on Dan's comment, here's how to [import a Jupyter notebook as a Python module](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html)

Comment: You are right, this is for a specific task where I am writing a book and want to copy code from a code cell of one chapter to the code cell of a different chapter (each chapter is a notebook). If I just do import, then the reader doesn't see the code, which makes for unpleasant reading. %load allows for loading from a python file, but I want to load a code cell from a notebook. Anybody know a trick of how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Adapting some code found [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html#Aside:-displaying-notebooks) at Jupyter Notebook, the following will display the code of a specific cell in the specified notebook:

```py
import io
from nbformat import read

def print_cell_code(fname, cellno):
    with io.open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        nb = read(f, 4)
    cell = nb.cells[cellno]
    print(cell.source)

print_cell_code("Untitled.ipynb",2)
```

Not sure what you want to do once the code is there, but maybe this can be adapted to suit your needs.  Try `print(nb.cells)` to see what `read` brings in.

Comment: This is almost  what I want. Once I have the cell.source, I want to get that into a code cell so I (or the user) can execute it, like the %load magic command. Any thought on how to achieve that interactively (maybe I can find that in the %load code, but I have a hard time finding that).

Comment: I think `%load cell.source` works to get what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use or write your own [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) preprocessor to extract a cell from one and insert into another.  There is a good amount research into these docs it takes to understand how to write your preprocessor, but this is the preferred way.

The quick fix option you have is that the nbformat specification is predicated on JSON, which means that if you read in a `ipynb` file with pure python (ie with `open` and `read`), you can call `json.loads` on it to turn the entire file into a `dict`.  From there, you can access cells in the `cells` entry (which is a `list` of cells).  So, something like like this:

```py
import json

with open("nb1.ipynb", "r") as nb1, open("nb2.ipynb", "r") as nb2:
    nb1, nb2 = json.loads(nb1.read()), json.loads(nb2.read())
    nb2["cells"].append(nb1["cells"][0]) # adds nb1's first cell to end of nb2
```

This assumes (as does your question) there is no metadata conflict between the notebooks.